# Demander à vous faire appeler

Tags: prépositions, verbes

Quelqu'un m'a écrit :

> Je demanderai **à** vous faire appeler pour qu'on en discute.

La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5220) dit à ce sujet :

> La préposition *à* est utilisée lorsque le sujet de demander est le même
> que le sujet sous-entendu de l’infinitif.

Dans sa phrase, il s'agit de deux sujets différents. Pourquoi alors il y a un *à* et non *de* après *demander* ?

Answer (score 4):

Le sujet réel est le même : je demanderai, je vous ferai appeler. *Je* n'est pas celui qui veut appeller, mais c'est celui qui veut faire.

(J'ai du mal à imaginer un contexte où la phrase n'aurait pas pu être « Je vous ferai appeler pour qu'on en discute ». Demander à faire appeler signifie que A demande à B de s'arranger pour que C appelle, et en faisant cela, A s'arrange pour que C appelle.)

Comment: Merci. J'ai aussi trébuché sur _demander à faire appeler_. Voici le contexte : A, B et C sont des collègues, A m'a écrit ce message, et, quelques minutes plus tard, B m'a appelée. Mais B est lié avec C, donc B a pu m'appeler et discuter avec moi parce qu'il et C se sont accordés avant. // _je demanderai, je vous ferai appeler_ Je ne comprends pas. Donc, A demande à C de parler à B pour que B m'appelle ? Ou A demande à B de m'appeler est aussi possible ?

Comment: @Oreste Si on prend la phrase à la lettre, A a demandé à C de s'arranger pour que quelqu'un t'appelle, et C a demandé à B de t'appeler. Bien sûr, il est aussi possible qu'il n'y ait pas de C, et que A utilise juste trop de mots.